# Excel Formula =Ax&Bx&Cx&Dx... when merged cell appears

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working with big table with structure similar to picture below, but more columns(A-AZ) and really more rows. And for some reason I need to get whole row into one string, like you can see as "Expected result", but I'm getting really bad data. Do you know how to get right results? Without VBA, if possible

[image]

OK, I don't know how to close this question, but I'm closing it by this. I'm using merged cells, because it's required to use them, and everybody here yells, that merged cells are evil so **this question is closed as unsolvable**.

Comment: There might be a non-vba solution to this the way you want it, but if possible I'd recommend just un-merging all your cells. It's the fastest solution, if that's possible.

Comment: Unmerging is probably the way to go here. Why do you need the cells to be merged?

Comment: If you haven't guessed, using Merged Cells isn't best practice. It's usually better to repeat the data, and if you only want to show one, make the text white. Or, keep your merged cell, but include a column next to it with all the cells filled in. (FYI, [here's](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/ExcelSpreadsheetDesign.htm) just one page outlining some good practices for Excel).

Comment: **You have a bad spreadsheet design** - don't use merged cells for referenced data. You should fix your design, not cater to it with unnecessary complex formulae.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the comments from mattdeak and Brad, the issue is that cells `A3:A6` are merged.  As a result, the value "Lamp" is actually only in cell `A3`, and cells `A4:A6` are blank.  Therefore, `J4` sees `A4=""` and `B4=""`, giving you the indicated result (only the value in `C4`).

The easiest way, as the commenters noted, is to unmerge the cells and copy all the data into each row.  If your cells have to stay merged, I recommend the approach used in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/841420/269989).  Here's how it works:

1. Pick a space where you can add a second set of Table columns.  I'll use `CA` since you said you have columns `A-AZ`.
2. In `CA3`, enter the formula `=IF(ISBLANK(A3),CA2,A3)`.
3. Fill right from `CA3` through `DZ3`.  `DZ3` should thus refer to `AZ3`.
4. Fill down `CA3:DZ3` for as many rows as you have.  At this point. `CA3:DZ<last row>` is a copy of your table with everything filled in.
5. Update the formula to be `=CA3 & CB3 & ...` for however many columns you need to merge.  Use the values from `CA:DZ` and you should be OK!

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a little VBA, you can create a User Function in a public module as follow:

```
Public Function MergedValue(r As Range) As Range
    Application.Volatile
    If Not r.MergeCells Then
       Set MergedValue = r
    Else
       Set MergedValue = r.MergeArea.Cells(1, 1)
    End If
End Function
```

Then replace all `=Ax & Bx & Cx ...` formulas by `=MergedValue(Ax) & MergedValue(Bx) & MergedValue(Cx) ...`

**Edit:** Added `Application.Volatile` at the start

**Edit 2:** Without using `Application.Volatile`

```
Public Function MergedValue(r As Range, RangeToCheck as range) As Range
    If Not r.MergeCells Then
       Set MergedValue = r
    Else
       Set MergedValue = r.MergeArea.Cells(1, 1)
    End If
End Function
```

Call it with `=MergedValue(A1,$A$1:$C$3)` for example if you want to check cells in range [A1:C3].

Comment: Works fine directly after formula is inserted.For example if I merge A1 & A2, insert "Hello" and enter formulas to B1 = MergedValue(A1) and B2 = MergedValue(A2), everything is fine. In B1 is "Hello" and in B2 is "Hello". But when I  change "Hello" to "Hi", B1 gets value "Hi" and B2 stays on "Hello"

Comment: It is because of the way Excel refresh cells. When you change the value of the merged cell, you only change the value of A1, and only cells that directly reference A1 will be updated. Simply add `Application.Volatile`at the start of the function.

Comment: Wow, it works :-) Althought I'm now waiting 10 seconds to recalculate, when one value is changed :-D On i7 CPU :-D Is here any way to recalculate only all rows inside r ? (r As Range)

Comment: Yes it is, you will need to add a second parameter to the function and set it to the full range to be checked

Answer (score -1):

```
=concat(offset(A3,-mod(row()+3,6),,4)) & concat(offset(B3, -mod(row()+1,2),,2)) & C3 & concat(offset(D3,-mod(row()+3,6),,4)) & concat(offset(E3, -mod(row()+1,2),,2)) & concat(offset(F3, -mod(row()+1,2),,2))
```

to get A column: in j3, -mod(row()+3,6) = 0. so concat(offset(A3,0,0,4)) = A3&A4&A5&A6 = A3.

to get B column: in j3, -mod(row()+1,2) = 0. so cancat(offset(B3,0,0,2)) = B3&B4 = B3.

And so on D, E, F column.

---

**There is another method (writed on 2016/6/20)**

step 1.Select A3 cell and press `Ctrl + A`.

step 2.Then press `Ctrl + 1` (The "1" key with "!", Not the "1" in number pad)

step 3.Select "Alignment" tag, disable "Merge Cells"

step 4.Then "Home" -> "Find & Select" -> "Go to special" -> select "Blanks"  (the short cut key sequence is: `Alt` -> `h` -> `f` -> `d` -> `s` -> `k` -> `Enter`)

step 5.The active cell be B4, then write `=b3` and press `ctrl + Enter`

step 6.Then in J3 cell write down: `=CONCATENATE(A3,B3,C3,D3,E3,F3)` or `=CONCAT(A3:F3)`

Comment: When coppied to row below (4), again writes only "Right" like on my example

Comment: Yes, in the case below row 4, you have to reset the mod() function.   I just write another method.